# Camel AWS SNS - Topic not found

Tags: apache-camel, integration

I am trying to send a message to AWS SNS using Camel. As far as I know, the topic is there (I have verified the case and spelling for the topic as well). But Camel gives the error "topic not found". I am not sure why this happens.

com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Topic Name (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 5c5607b4-179e-5698-8994-54e8ab3dcb41

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be the region you are using is different from the topic's region. Where are you specifying the region?

Comment: Thanks Ram. I specify the region in the route itself.

Comment: from("timer:kickoff?period=5000").log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"*** Step 10 
    ***")
    .setBody()
     .method(this, "generateJsonString")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"***** Before sending message *****")
    .to("aws-sns://arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:XXX:sampleTopic? 
     proxyHost=XXX&proxyPort=XXX&accessKey=XXYY&secretKey=SSYY")
    .log("***** After sending message *****");

Comment: To be specific, in the URI. I also tried option region = format as well. But that also did not work..